# KSP apoption does not match \S+=\S+: room.internal.schemaInput=C:\Users\Aditya\My Projects\zomato\app\schemas

Tags: android, kotlin

This problem is occurring after updating Gradle plugin and updating Android Studio to version canary 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending more time, I found working fix for this:

The project folder path shouldn't have any spaces in it, like in the error log above. For example, the project path **C:\Users\Aditya\My Projects\zomato** contains spaces in the folder name for the **My Projects** folder. I was able to fix this by just eliminating the space and rename folder to **MyProjects**.

New project path - **C:\Users\Aditya\MyProjects\zomato**

Reference - [here](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/issues/604#issuecomment-1444626840)